# I add all the files in the directory into an enumproperty,as the files may change from time to time, how to update the enumproperty?

Tags: python

```
txtfiles: EnumProperty(
        items=my_txt_files_callback,
        name="texts",
        description="",
        get=get_filtered_txt_file_list,
        set=set_filtered_txt_file_list,
        update=update_directory,
        )
```

Once my_txt_files_callback call back function is finished loading when Blender starts, how to change the values when the files in the directory are changed afterwards?

Comment: Hello ! I don't think there is a trivial way to detect when the contents of an outside directory changes. Parsing the contents of a directory should not be a performance bottleneck unless you have thousands of files, and at this point having an `EnumProperty` is unmanageable. Have you tried simply fetching the directory contents every time you want to draw the property ?

Comment: As an alternative you can create an `Operator` and actively update the contents of your `items` callback when you click on a button in the interface or link it to a keymap item to execute it with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks!  I have added an operator class to update the contents. Shall I need to call the my_txt_files_callback(self, context) inside the operator class again?

Answer (score 1):

The update callback should return the same "value" (e.g. all the file names in a directory) as the items callback.

```
import bpy

from pathlib import Path

root = r"F:\scripts\tests"

root_path = Path(root)

def file_items(self, context):
    files = []
    for i, file in enumerate(root_path.iterdir()):
        item = (file.name.upper(), file.name, f"the description {i}")
        files.append(item)
    return files

bpy.types.Scene.test_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=file_items, update=file_items)
```

If I put this into a UILayout.prop it updates in realtime when I manipulate the files in this directory.

Comment: Hello ! Sorry but I think this answer is wrong. [According to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) the `update` method should take two parameters `self` and `context` and return `None`. Having an `update` callback return something else will print out in the console an error `ValueError: the return value must be None`

Comment: @Gorgious Agreed with you said. But worthy of trying update with a different function name.

Comment: @Gorgious I have tested update method as what you suggested is correct, update will return None, so there is no option to update the items in enumproperty after Blender running?

Comment: I don't know, I tested this exact code in blender before posting here, and it worked fine on my end. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯